# WordPress shortcode to plain HTML?

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

Is there any way to reverse WordPress shortcode tags to get plain HTML?

The only solution I have come up with has been to parse out any HTML contained between the tags, however this doesn't work with some plugins like Caldera Forms.

Example from WP docs:

```
[caption id="attachment_6" align="alignright" width="300"]<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/800px-Great_Wave_off_Kanagawa2-300x205.jpg" alt="Kanagawa" title="The Great Wave" width="300" height="205" class="size-medium wp-image-6" /> The Great Wave[/caption]
```

Expected:

```
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/800px-Great_Wave_off_Kanagawa2-300x205.jpg" alt="Kanagawa" title="The Great Wave" width="300" height="205" class="size-medium wp-image-6" /> 
The Great Wave
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here -as user3934205 also wonders below- so providing a bit more context/actual code/examples would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try inspecting the element using Chrome dev tools to see what's rendered. Then you can copy that. Knowing your ultimate goal could be helpful